# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/PropertyException

Tags: allure

I'm getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/PropertyException exception when trying to open an allure report.

I got as far as generating the allure-results folder in my target class, where my surefire reports are also being generated.

When I try allure serve projectpath\target\ or allure serve projectpath\target\surefire-reports I get the following exception -

Generating report to temp directory...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/PropertyException
at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.xmlFiles(Allure1Plugin.java:393)
at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.getStreamOfAllure1Results(Allure1Plugin.java:388)

My pom file looks like this. The reason I am using some old versions of these is because those are the versions that exist in our artifactory. They will all be updated to current versions soon.

'''

```
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>${testSuite}</suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--<reportsDirectory>test-output/</reportsDirectory>-->
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <testSuite>config/smokeTest.xml</testSuite>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.8</aspectj.version>
</properties>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I was using Java 11, but Allure needs to be compiled using Java 8.